# Clearing unused iis websites

Tags: asp.net, iis, webserver, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have 20 websites under my IIS webserver(with Window server 2008 R2).

Now I need to clear some unused websites. How to do that?

At least can I see the last usage of the website from any source of the server?

Thank you

Comment: IIS log files are stored by default in the %SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles folder of your IIS server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,  there is no other way to identify the unused website except checking the last request datetime in IIS log.
In the IIS log path C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVCx(x is the ID of your website) . Once you get the site ID, you can go to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationhost.config to get site name.The binding would look like:

```
 <site name="Default Web Site" id="1" serverAutoStart="false">
```

Finally, you can delete the website from IIS manager GUI or Powershell.

[Remove-IISSite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/remove-iissite?view=win10-ps)

Best regards,

Sam